# Android Studio Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

I have the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. >
>   Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    android:label="FaceTracker">
    <activity        
android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.
face.facetracker.FaceTrackerActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="Face Tracker"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

and for **build.gradle** as follows

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
   compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.facetracker"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),       
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'],dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
compile 'com.empatica.empalink:empalink:2.1@aar'}
```

I have tried other solutions provided here on stack overflow but none worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: The error message told you "... see logs". So what do you find in log?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the question to display the error as a quote, to highlight it. I also added the android-manifest tag.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and the error occurred because of the Bottom line change:

```
    android:supportsRtl="false"
```

The error was fixed when I changed "false" to "true":

```
    android:supportsRtl="true"
```

In my opinion, this error returns to your last change in the manifest, see the last Time what you changed.
I hope to work for you.
I also have another offer, you can refer to page "merged Manifest" in your AndroidManifest.xml  and see your own error

Answer (score 0):

A spelling error?

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'
```

should be

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-version:9.4.0+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything repeated within one manifest file example Activity, Service declaration can cause this issue.